# Returning value from function inside a function

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, return-value, return, nested-function

I'm using `goMap` and I'm trying to add a function inside it, but I cannot get it to return when the function is called. If I use `alert()` inside the function, it has the values I need it that should be returned.

```
getAddress: function(latlngcoords)
{
    var goMap = this;
    var input = latlngcoords;
    var latlngStr = input.split(",", 2);
    var lat = parseFloat(latlngStr[0]);
    var lng = parseFloat(latlngStr[1]);
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    var address;

    geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) 
    {
        if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 
        {
            if(results) 
            {   
                address = results;
                //alert(address); <-- works but
            }
        }
    });

    return address; // won't return at all?
},
```

It's called by doing: `$.goMap.getAddress()` but with a latitude and longitude in the argument. I need it to return the values by `return address` but it won't return anything at all.

How will I be able to get it to return the value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`geocode` is an *asynchronous* function. It *starts* when you call it, but that's all. (That's why it accepts a callback.) So your `getAddress` function is returning before `address` is set by the callback.

You need to have your `getAddress` function accept a callback as well, and return the result that way, e.g.

```
getAddress: function(latlngcoords, callback)
                                // ^--- callback parameter
{
    var goMap = this;
    var input = latlngcoords;
    var latlngStr = input.split(",", 2);
    var lat = parseFloat(latlngStr[0]);
    var lng = parseFloat(latlngStr[1]);
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    var address;

    geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) 
    {
        if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 
        {
            if(results) 
            {   
                address = results;
                callback(address);
            //  ^--- call it with the result
            }
        }
    });
},
```

Naturally this means that the code *calling* `getAddress` has to handle the fact that `getAddress` is also asynchronous.

Comment: So there is no method of able to return the data somehow?

Comment: Firebug says `callback is not a function`

Comment: Oh, forgot to save changes. Thanks for this. :)